# Reputation and upvotes mismatch

Tags: bug, reputation, up-votes

How is it possible that [this user](https://stackexchange.com/users/965625/peter-penzov) has so many up-voted questions and gold medals in StackOverflow and at the same time such a low reputation? I'd expect it to be way higher than that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103606/peter-penzov?tab=bounties&sort=offered):

> [image]

This is also visible in the user's [Reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103606/peter-penzov?tab=reputation), and in the mini graph:

> [image]

(Meaning you see the reputation rise, then getting down, due to the bounties)